# Angular DI useFactory pass a parameter to the factory function

Tags: angular

How to pass a parameter (number) to a factory function:

```
const id = 1;

{ provide: MyClass, useFactory: myFactory, deps: [ActivatedRoute] }


//how to pass the id here?
function myFactory(id, activatedRoute) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
const id = 1;

{ provide: MyClass, useFactory: (route:ActivatedRoute)=>myFactory(id,route), deps: [ActivatedRoute] }

function myFactory(id, activatedRoute) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, you can either use `bind` to pass in arguments or you can use `dependency injection` to configure the argument, please find below working example!

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import 'zone.js';

//how to pass the id here?
function myFactory(id: any, activatedRoute: any) {
  console.log(id, activatedRoute);
}
class MyClass {}
class MyClassW {}
const id = 1;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyClass,
      useFactory: myFactory.bind(this, id),
      deps: [ActivatedRoute],
    },
    {
      provide: MyClassW,
      useFactory: myFactory.bind(this, id),
      deps: [, new Inject(id), ActivatedRoute],
    },
  ],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private myClass: MyClass) {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(RouterModule), provideRouter([])],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wwcdhv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)